# conda pyqt import failed in a new virtual environment

Tags: import, virtualenv, pyqt5, conda

I tried to run programs using pyqt.

It worked if I didn't use a virtual environment but if I activated a virtual environment, it would fail: ImportError: DLL load failed...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "submitA2.py", line 14, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "C:\Users\jerem\Anaconda3\envs\deep\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 116, in <module>
    _backend_mod, new_figure_manager, draw_if_interactive, _show = pylab_setup()
  File "C:\Users\jerem\Anaconda3\envs\deep\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\__init__.py", line 60, in pylab_setup
    [backend_name], 0)
  File "C:\Users\jerem\Anaconda3\envs\deep\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_qt5agg.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .backend_qt5 import (
  File "C:\Users\jerem\Anaconda3\envs\deep\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_qt5.py", line 18, in <module>
    import matplotlib.backends.qt_editor.figureoptions as figureoptions
  File "C:\Users\jerem\Anaconda3\envs\deep\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\qt_editor\figureoptions.py", line 20, in <module>
    import matplotlib.backends.qt_editor.formlayout as formlayout
  File "C:\Users\jerem\Anaconda3\envs\deep\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\qt_editor\formlayout.py", line 56, in <module>
    from matplotlib.backends.qt_compat import QtGui, QtWidgets, QtCore
  File "C:\Users\jerem\Anaconda3\envs\deep\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\qt_compat.py", line 137, in <module>
    from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

I can't install another pyqt package in this virtual environment because it tells me:

```
# All requested packages already installed.
# packages in environment at C:\Users\jerem\Anaconda3\envs\deep:
#
pyqt                      5.6.0                    py36_4    conda-forge
```

How to fix this?? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A not perfect solution: installing a different version of PyQt5 seems to get around this issue.

```
activate myenv
conda install pyqt=5.9
```

Answer (score 1):

Jeremy Chen's solution is the only solution that worked for me. i.e

`conda install pyqt=5.9` within your conda environment

All other solutinos listed on internet did not work.
But this installation of pytqt=5.9 breaks matplotlib module with the following error when trying

`import matplotlib`

> ImportError: cannot import name 'get_backend'

This was solved by using

`conda uninstall matplotlib`

and then reinstalling

`conda install matplotlib`

Comment: This can be a comment, not an answer.